# How to prove that in the continuous case $E[m] = P(x \in S)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have $m_{x \in S}$ which is 1 when $x \in S$ and $0$ otherwise.

We want to prove that $E[m_{x \in S}] = P(x \in S)$.

By definition $P(x \in S) = \int_{x \in S} f(x)dx$ = 1

There seems to be an obvious link between $P(x \in S)$ and $m_{x \in S}$ because of the 1 but the expectation is throwing me off. I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: $x$ is a random variable, right? How did you get $f$ in that formula for $\mathbb P( x \in S)$, is it density? It shouldn't be $1$, right? Then simply $ \mathbb E[m_{x \in S}] = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)m_{x \in S} dx = \int_{S} f(x)dx  = \mathbb P(x \in S)$. Note that in the last equality it is $\int_{S}$, not $\int_{x \in S}$. It is worth to mention that in holds in general setting, namely for any event $A$ you have $\mathbb P(A)  = \mathbb E[m_A]$ where $m_A(\omega)=1$ if $\omega \in A$ and $0$ otherwise (although more common notation is $\chi_A$ or $1_A$ instead of $m_A$, which you used)

Comment: Ok but why does $E[m_{x \in S}] = \int_{R} f(x)m_{x \in S} dx$? I thought the formula for the expectation is usually $E[X] = \int x f(x) dx$ where is the equivalent of little x ? Is it $m_{x \in S}$? Why?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb E[X] = \int xf(x)dx$ and $\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int g(x)f(x) dx$ (do you know the second formula? it is rather basic). Use it with $g(X) = m_{X \in S}$